# JPA Relationship issue

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

I'm working on a project, and I encountered a problem with the JPA relationship. I've been advised on another thread to change a couple of things, however, I still can't get it to work properly.

I'm getting an exception and I know where the problem is but not sure how to solve it.

here is the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Car> cars;

}
```

here is the Car class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(length = 11)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "make", nullable = false)
    private String make;

    @Column(name = "model", nullable = false)
    private String model;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id") //here is where the exception throws (duplicated ID or com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user_model_id' in 'field list' if I change that to user_model_id.
    private UserModel userModel;

}
```

here is the service impl:

```
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

@Inject
private CarRepository carRepository;

@Inject
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Car addCar(Long userId, Car car) {
    User user = userRepository.findOne(userId);      
    user.getCars().add(car);

    car.setUser(user);
    carRepository.save(car);

    return car; 
}
```

Any help will be really much appreciated.

Thank you so much

Comment: Could you please link to the other thread you mentioned? Also, please post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I don't found this method in your code snippet: user.getGpsLocationModels()

Comment: Hi Cascer, thank you for your reply. Please find the edited post with the other thread and full stacktrace

Comment: Hi Naman, Sorry it was a typo, it was getCars (an ArrayList collection). Thank you for the spot.

Comment: so you have an exception complaining about some SQL that Hibernate generates ... and don't post the actual SQL! Also you don't say WHAT operation you were invoking to cause the exception .... the FULL stack trace would tell that

Comment: The SQL is from hibernate. I'm not running any customised SQL, it's by default from the repository.

Comment: Could you please post your persistence.xml (after removing login information)

Comment: "The SQL is from hibernate". Yes, and? WHERE IS IT? In the JPA providers log. The exception doesn't appear at some `@JoinColumn` ... it appears from some SQL from an operation, maybe related to your mapping

Comment: I'm not using persistence.xml as I'm leaving spring-boot to handle that for me. I'm going to post the repository as well if that helps :)

Comment: I'm going to post the full stacktrace right now :)

Comment: Neil, please find attached the full stacktrace as it comes up in terminal. thank you so much :)

Comment: Your mapping of a 1-N bidir FK relation is basically WRONG. You cannot use the PK of the N side as the FK to the 1 side! (since then you can only have 1 element in each collection!!!). You need a separate FK column. All JPA reference docs that you will find tell you clearly enough how to do this. Here http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/one_to_many_collection.html#fk_bi

Comment: And it is wrong because your `@JoinColumn` annotation carries the incorrect value.

Comment: Issue solved @Neil Stockton. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  `mappedBy` needs to point to the field name that owns the relation. In this case this is `userModel` so it should be

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userModel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the  mappedBy element must be
>   used to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that
>   is the owner of the relationship. (from https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany)

Also I think that your `@JoinColumn` annotation is wrong. It should specify the column used to join the related entity - so it cannot be `ID` but something like `user_id`

See https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/JoinColumn#

Also your ddl is wrong - this piece says that cars and users have the same id - which you do not want - your ddl is missing the actual column for the user foreign key

```
FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES game.user (id)
```

So if you changed JoinColumn to `@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")` your ddl for the foreign key must be.

```
CREATE TABLE game.car (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
    make VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    model VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)  COMMENT '',
    user_id INT(11),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES game.user (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

If I can add my 2 cents to the mapping  - try to avoid bidirectional relations wherever you can.

Comment: Hi Mathias, I've changed the mappedBy to userModel but still no difference. :(. Regarding the @JoinColumn I've tried them all still no luck. The foreign key is fk_user.id in the DB

Comment: I've been advised to use bidirectional from another thread in order to retrieve one and all cars for a particular user. Initially I haven't used bidirectional but that's how I've been told by someone, might worth a try, however, still doesn't work as it should

Comment: Yes, the fk is in the car table with the name fk_user and the reference column is id.

Comment: I just gave it a try - with my proposals regarding `mappedBy` and `JoinColumn` I can persist the entities. I was using an in-memory db for the test. I think your schema is not correct in the db - how did you create it?  run it with spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true against an empty db and check again

Comment: let me post it quickly to show you how's been created :). Something is very odd to me, as I think it looks good the mappings, that's why I can't figure it out.

Comment: Mathias, please find the DB creation script in the initial post. thank you so much for all your help

Comment: @Neil, I've tried that too, it doesn't look like it does work, that got me very confused. "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'fk_user' in 'field list'"

Comment: please bear with me as I'm getting an exception regarding SQL "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint" and I'm trying to figure out why's that.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Thank you so much for your help. Currently I'm getting an overflow exception but I should be ok with that. Thank you once again